# How can I get text to NOT overlap in Small Basic?

Tags: windows, text, overlap, basic, smallbasic

I need to have a graphics window that displays a message over and over again as a user clicks a button. I have looked all over the internet for instructions on how to not make it overlap.  This is most likely a quick fix but idk. Plz help here is my code. I am trying to make a clicker game but haulted as this issue happened.

```
GraphicsWindow.Height = 420
GraphicsWindow.Width = 720
GraphicsWindow.CanResize = "1"

button = Controls.AddButton("Click for eggs",200,200)
Controls.SetSize(button,100,100)

eggs = 0

Controls.ButtonClicked = buttonClicked

Sub buttonClicked

lastButtonClicked = Controls.LastClickedButton

If lastButtonClicked = button Then
eggs = eggs + 1
GraphicsWindow.DrawText(0,0,"You have " + eggs + " eggs")   
ElseIf eggs >= 1 Then  
GraphicsWindow.BackgroundColor = "White"
GraphicsWindow.DrawText(0,0,"You have " + eggs + " eggs")  
EndIf
EndSub
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this exact effect isn't possible in Small Basic, because things drawn to the `GraphicsWindow` can't be edited or removed without clearing the entire window.

Instead, I would use a `TextBox` from `Controls`, which can be edited after they've been created. Because the `TextBox` can normally be edited by the user, I've also added code to prevent the content from being edited.

See my comments in the code for more about how this works.

```
GraphicsWindow.Height = 420
GraphicsWindow.Width = 720
GraphicsWindow.CanResize = "1"

button = Controls.AddButton("Click for eggs",200,200)
Controls.SetSize(button,100,100)

eggs = 0

Controls.ButtonClicked = buttonClicked

' Create a text box to show the egg count
myTextBox = Controls.AddTextBox(0, 0)

' Ensure the user can't edit its contents by resetting the text if it changes
Controls.TextTyped = updateEggs

Sub updateEggs
  ' Change the text of myTextBox
  Controls.SetTextBoxText(myTextBox, "You have " + eggs + " eggs")   
EndSub

Sub buttonClicked
  lastButtonClicked = Controls.LastClickedButton

  If lastButtonClicked = button Then
    eggs = eggs + 1
    updateEggs()
  ElseIf eggs >= 1 Then  
    GraphicsWindow.BackgroundColor = "White"
    updateEggs()
  EndIf
EndSub
```

This GIF demonstrates how the `TextBox` looks and works, as well as how the text cannot be changed:

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use Shapes.AddText. This will create a text shape that can be modified with Shapes.SetText

Example:

```
GraphicsWindow.Height = 420
GraphicsWindow.Width = 720
GraphicsWindow.CanResize = "1"

Text = Shapes.AddText("You have 0 eggs")

button = Controls.AddButton("Click for eggs",200,200)
Controls.SetSize(button,100,100)

eggs = 0

Controls.ButtonClicked = buttonClicked

Sub buttonClicked
lastButtonClicked = Controls.LastClickedButton

If lastButtonClicked = button Then
eggs = eggs + 1
Shapes.SetText(Text,"You have " + eggs + " eggs")   
EndIf
EndSub
```